# sending email time out in azure web services

Tags: azure, email, smtp, timeout, iredmail

I have a .NET webapp hosted as azure web service, working flawlessly until few days.

The app features to send the invoices / reminders to customers, which are being sent through external SMTP provider (iredmail configured in AWS server).

From last week or so, no mails are being sent from that app and there is no update in the app in recent past. And the logged message just says "request timed out". I tried with higher timeout value too in (smtp.Timeout = 20000)

I have tried with changing the mail id, and even the domain (hosted in same iredmail), none would work.

Then I tried to do same operation from my dev machine (local), the mails are sent from all the email / domains, failed earlier. I have published same code and tried again, just in case, but results same.

Is there any update in azure all at once to block the external SMTP service? of course the port is 587 and all were working till few days back.

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.